# SQL update field based on conditions of another field

Tags: sql, select, sql-update, case, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Super noob here.

I want to update column AI_Amount to 0 whenever column Delete_Field = C.

When a customer leaves the delete_field gets updated to a C but the AI_Amount field will not zero out. How do I go about doing this?

I tried using the update clause but it says I don't have permission. I don't want to update the actual table just the query results.

Comment: Please show what you have tried, or accept the answer from @GMB

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please consider checking out  [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), SO is for solving specific problems with programming, you should provide a code you have tried so far, describe problems and show effort in trying to solve it yourself at first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't want to update the actual table just the query results.

You seem to want `select`, not `update`:

```
select 
    delete_field,
    case when delete_field = 'C' then 0 else ai_amount end as ai_amount,
    -- other columns here
from mytable
```